# Writing a simple MySQL replace query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, replace

I've got two tables, one that looks like this:

```
ID | Date ID | Data
```

And another that looks like this:

```
Date ID | Date
```

Can you help me construct a query that will basically eliminate the need for the second table? I'd rather have the first table be: `ID | Date | Data`

If this isn't possible with a MySQL query, is there a quick PHP script that I should write to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your assumption is fine  with id , date , data

Comment: So are you looking for merging the two tables data? update? insert from one table to  another? can you please explain?

Comment: I'm looking to merge the tables.

Comment: @AC360 So, Please edit your question explaining that in more details with some sample data and the desired output after merging these data how the two tables should look like.

Answer (score 3):

You will need the second table because you want to join them. Right?

```
SELECT  a.ID, b.Date, a.Data
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.DataID = b.DataID
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In your query, can you define what `a`, `b`, `table1` and `table2` are?

Comment: `a` and `b` are ALIAS for table names. It helps you minimize the the query for longer table names.

Comment: Ahh I see, can you define the alias after you've used it? For example, in your above query, you've used `a` before defining `table1` as `a`. Thanks again for helping me out!

Comment: no, you must be sure that the tables were given an alias before they can be used. The reason why you see `SELECT a.ID,...` is because in the SQL Order of Operations, the `FROM` clause is executed first, so when you it on `SELECT` clause, you now use the alias. An error will be thrown if for instance you execute this query `SELECT a.ID FROM table1`.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about the database normalization. If you leave these two tables as it is then your records will be less redundant. But as you eliminate the second table, the Date field will be repeated more frequently. So, I suggest you to have both the tables since it is an efficient practice.

Query can be constructed in both the ways.
For two tables, you should use the join query as:

```
SELECT f.ID, s.Date, f.Data
FROM table1 f
            INNER JOIN table2 s
            ON f.DateID=s.DateID
```

If you eliminate the second table and have the first table with columns **ID, Date, Data** then the query could simply be:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Data
FROM table1
           WHERE (filter conditions..)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In your first query, can you define what `f`, `s`, `table1` and `table2` are? Does this query actually join the first table with the second? Also, if I leave it as two separate tables to increase the redundancy, don't I have to do two queries to grab all the info on the data? One to grab the line from the first table and another to grab the specified date? Doesn't that end up being less efficient?

Comment: oh, f and s are alias to table1 and table2, the two tables and the join condition is Corrected!!

Answer (score 2):

1) create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE table3
(
id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
date DATE,
data TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

2) Insert into the new created table the data you requested from the previous tables:

```
INSERT INTO
table3 
SELECT 
table1.id, 
table1.data, 
table2.date 
FROM 
table1, table2 
WHERE 
table1.date_id = table2.date_id
```